# I'm trying to test COW on Collection Types. But it didn't work

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to test COW on Collection Types such as Arrays, Set and dictionaries. But it didn't work on Set and Dictionaries. Here're my code and memory addresses of them. Please help.

```swift
var aArray: [Int] = [0, 1, 2, 3]
var bArray = aArray

var aSet: Set = [0, 1, 2]
var bSet = aSet

var aDictionary = ["0": 0]

for i in 0..<10000 {
    aDictionary.updateValue(i, forKey: "\(i)")
}
var bDictionary = aDictionary

address(of: &aArray) // 0x600001370ea0
address(of: &bArray) // 0x600001370ea0 // Array is okay
address(of: &aSet) // 0x10244c5a0
address(of: &bSet) // 0x10244c5a8 
address(of: &aDictionary) // 0x10244c5b0
address(of: &bDictionary) // 0x10244c5b8 // But they are different
```

I expected Set and Dictionaries had same addresses before modifying values because of COW.

Comment: these are value type variables not reference type, so it may not refer to same memory address. You can use reference DataType like NSArray, NSSet, etc

Comment: I am acronym-impaired. What does COW stand for?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But According to COW(Copy-On-Write) mechanism, even though Collection Types are value type, they are supposed to have same memory address before changing values. Did I know something wrong? I am confused..

Comment: COW stands for Copy-On-Write.

Comment: "even though Collection Types are value type, they are supposed to have same memory address before changing values." This is not correct at all. COW types are still value types and may be copied to a new address when they are passed. Just their **backing storage** is shared and avoids copying. COW is entirely feature of stdlib implementation (it's just code). It's not actually part of the core language. Start here, and then dig into how _ArrayBuffer works internally: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/stdlib/public/core/Array.swift

Comment: ("it's just code" is a little bit of an overstatement. The stdlib implementations do have some things that may not be 100% implementable in your own Swift, but you can still implement your own COW using `isKnownUniquelyReferenced` and a backing buffer, which is ultimately what stdlib is doing)

Comment: Thank you I will look for it! If you don't mind, Could I ask you one more question? Then, why do only Array have a same address when they are passed? It's a Collection Type. Does it have something to do with ArrayBuffer? I'm sorry for bothering you.

Comment: Given how small your Array is, it may be due to optimizations. The optimizer may also note that you didn't modify it and aliases the values. I don't know how `address(of:)` is implemented. (The very fact that you forced the value to have an address modifies how the code works, btw. Arrays can be highly optimized in some cases.) I'd look at `-emit-sil` output with and without `-O` to see better what's going on. If this is Playgrounds, that output is meaningless.

Comment: The address of a value type isn't really well defined. It could be inlined or stored in a register.

Answer (score -1):

These are value type variables not reference type, so it may not refer to same memory address. You can use reference DataType like NSArray, NSSet, etc

```
var aArray1: NSArray = [0, 1, 2, 3]
var bArray1 = aArray1

var aSet1: NSSet = [0, 1, 2]
var bSet1 = aSet1
```

Now if you will check the reference will be same